# how do I deal with make errors during samsung source compile

Tags: android, makefile

I get the following errors when I try to issue make for Samsung Source:

```
@ubuntu:~/androidkernel$ sudo make
CHK     include/linux/version.h
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
CC      kernel/bounds.s
cc: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-mabi=aapcs-linux’
cc: note: valid arguments to ‘-mabi=’ are: ms sysv
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mlittle-endian’
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-thumb-interwork’
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

I did some online search, and found out that this may be due to discrepancy between the gcc toolchain and some other file. I am not sure if I am on the right path. I need help in figuring out how to address the above errors please.

Comment: I think this means you are missing the cross-compilation toolkit necessary for that architecture. Unfortunately I don't know what the correct solution to that is exactly though I would assume there should be packages available for it for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the souce downloaded then do the following

```
make ARCH=arm TOOLCHAIN=/pathtosource/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1516051

It is a complete description of the problem/solution.   Your problem is specifically at the "toolchain" part:

```
5) Download Arm Toolchain 

This toolchain will allow you to cross compile for your phone. There are several versions to choose. I currently use the 2010q1 version here: https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lit...ux-gnu.tar.bz2

Or choose another version if you like (version 2009q3 seems to be popular): https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lit...bscription3053
```

Another source of toolchain is from Android NDK (search for arm eabi directory):

https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

(it has to compile C, and so should include all the gcc cross toolchain to generate ARM binaries).

If you want an introduction, perhaps try this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PoENQiuYE4